# Public Bug Tracking and Version Control System

Tags: version-control, debug

We're in the process of moving out of a private beta into our live version of the site.

We're trying to find a good Bug Tracking System + Version Control system. Our CEO has requested that the new system be able to do the following things and I can't figure out where I can do this:

- Public facing Bug Tracker - Guests **don't** need to register to post OR ability to sync with current user tables to allow SSO.
- Ability to assign developers to posted bugs
- Integration with Version Control to allow Developers to attach bug to build version to confirm when the bug is fixed.
- Miscellaneous Project Management - Ability to create projects/tasks and assign them to developers or other administrative teams.

We are moving away from TeamBox.com as our Project Management suite as it just wasn't development oriented as we needed and we currently have no Version Control system.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: In general it's bad form to cross post on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @djmadscribbler I'd say not just in general it's bad form but nearly always bad form. I was just trying to hit a broad audience as I'm completely out of options. Thanks for your feedback though.

Answer (score 1):

OnTime provides all of the features you are requesting except for Version Control, but it does tie into github, which is nice.

There are also other products available that can be found by simply searching bug tracking or similar related searches.

Best of luck

Comment: Doesn't git do version control inherently?

Answer (score 0):

FogCreek software makes FogBugz and Kiln http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/pricing.html which an Issue Tracker/Project Manager (FogBugz) mixed with a version control (Kiln). Another very flexible tool is Jira http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview which does Issue Tracking, Project management and can also interface with Subversion, Git, Mercurial, Perforce, and CVS for version control. FogBugz is hosted solution whereas with Jira you'd need your own server.

Comment: Jira can be hosted too - they call it OnDemand (http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/pricing/?tab=ondemand)

Comment: Shouldn’t SE co-founder Joel be the one plugging FogBugz here? `:-)`